# iOS 5 [UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage does not do work

Tags: ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, background-image

I created a new test iOS5 project in Xcode 4.2 Build 4D199 and tried to set the appearance of the `UINavigationBar` as described above, but nothing happens.

The code I tried in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-iphone.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The only way I can get it to work is to set the appearance on the instance of the `UINavigationBar`.  Like:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-iphone.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

What is going on? Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: got the same problem, can set the tint and everything...

Answer (score 18):

`viewDidLoad` is the wrong place to be messing with the `appearance` proxy of a navigation controller's navigation bar. Do this sort of thing before the navigation controller is even created. In your app delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is a good place.

Comment: I had similar issue. On first push the navigationBar did not have the properties set using the appearance proxy. But on subsequent pop & push again it got its colors and images.
Looks like this "appearance" thingy cannot modify already allocated objects until their second appearance or so!!

Comment: Correct, @AnImIsH - My guess is that while something is visible it won't be redrawn by the appearance proxy.

Comment: It did put my code in applicationDidFinishLaunching.But I don't understand the exact reason or why it is not mentioned in Documentation

Answer (score 1):

Did you double-check if that Imagefile does exist?

Comment: Thats what it was with me, the image file didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide forBarMetrics: for this to work.