# Appearance in Xcode 4.2 doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, appearance

I added this code in my AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:221/256.0 green:36/256.0 blue:40/256.0 alpha:0.0]];

[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:221/256.0 green:36/256.0 blue:40/256.0 alpha:0.0]];
```

But NavigationBar and TabBar didn't change their color. What I have done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: See also: [iOS 5 UINavigationBar appearance setBackgroundImage does not do work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855365/ios-5-uinavigationbar-appearance-setbackgroundimage-does-not-do-work)

Comment: Yes, already fixed it, thanks! Now it works perfectly.
But what about UITabBar, it doesn't change its color like NavBar. Dont you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTintColor:` instead of setBackgroundColor:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:221/256.0 green:36/256.0 blue:40/256.0 alpha:0.0]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:221/256.0 green:36/256.0 blue:40/256.0 alpha:0.0]];
```

Comment: Ohh...right, crazy mistake. Thanks! But in this case, only NavigationBar changes it's color, and TabBar stills black. Dont you know why that happens?

Comment: Not sure, but you could try [this](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/06/04/tip-uitabbar-tint/) technique.

Comment: Oh, I found out why it doesnt work. My `alpha` color was 0.0
:D