# How to set the background of navigationbar in ios5 (Retina)?

Tags: iphone, ios

I use this code to set the background.
It do change the background, but there is some problem with Retina.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navi_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I have two pngs: navi_bar.png (320*44) and navi_bar@2x.png (640*88)

**The background of navigation bar always uses image navi_bar.png, even in Retina.**

If I use this code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navi_bar@2x.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The result is this in Retina:
[image]

The background has the double height...

I have spent the whole morning on this problem.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  UINavigationBar *navBarName = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
    UIImage *backgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navi_bar"];
    [navBarName setBackgroundImage:backgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Yes, I use your code to change the background in every viewcontroller. It works. But I have to write this code everywhere... Why does my code not work? Is it a bug of apple?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855365/ios-5-uinavigationbar-appearance-setbackgroundimage-does-not-do-work and check answer

Comment: The problem of the link is not the same with mine. My code can change the background, but the problem is that with Retina, the background still use navi_bar.png, not navi_bar@2x.png. I test your code, It can use the proper png in Retina.

Comment: see this link http://www.mladjanantic.com/setting-custom-background-for-uinavigationbar-what-will-work-on-ios5-and-ios4-too/ read when are you use [UINavigationBar appearance]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write `@"navi_bar@2x.png"`. iOS will automatically pick up the right image for retina display. Just use `@"navi_bar.png"`.

**EDIT-** [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575821/custom-nav-bar-styling-ios) will help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: NavBarBg.png is applied for retina device even though NavBarBg@2x.png is available. But it seems to be related with simulator only. When I run the app on device NavBarBg@2x.png is applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:aImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

in iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

This is weird you should check whether you have added the 2x image properly or not